# How to find the sum of the values stored in a binary tree of integers weighted by the depth of each value?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Explanation: For the given binary tree

```
              +---+
              | 9 |
              +---+
             /     \
         +---+     +---+
         | 7 |     | 6 |
         +---+     +---+
        /     \         \
    +---+     +---+     +---+
    | 3 |     | 2 |     | 4 |
    +---+     +---+     +---+
             /               \
         +---+               +---+
         | 5 |               | 2 |
         +---+               +---+
```

The sum would be computed as:

1 * 9 + 2 * (7 + 6) + 3 * (3 + 2 + 4) + 4 * (5 + 2) = 90

My approach to solve this is to find level of each node multiply it with the node's key and do it recursively for all nodes in the left and right sub-trees.

```
int weightedSumAtAllLevels(BTNode node) {
    if (node != null)
        return levelSumOfLeftSubTree(node.getLeftChild())
                + levelSumOfRightSubTree(node.getRightChild())
                + node.getKey();
    else
        return 0;
}

int levelSumOfLeftSubTree(BTNode tmp) {
    if (tmp == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int level = levelOfNode(tmp);
        return level * tmp.getKey()
                + levelSumOfLeftSubTree(tmp.getLeftChild());

    }
}

int levelSumOfRightSubTree(BTNode tmp) {
    if (tmp == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int level = levelOfNode(tmp);
        return level * tmp.getKey()
                + levelSumOfRightSubTree(tmp.getRightChild());
    }
}
int levelOfNode(BTNode node) {
    if (node == null)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + levelOfNode(node.getParent());
 }
```

It doesn't seem to work. I know this solution is flawed but I'm unable to fix it. Any help? suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that once you start going to the left, you keep going to the left. You never look at a right child of a left child, and vice versa.

You can compute the weighted sum with a single function that takes **both the node and its level**. This will simplify the implementation immensely, making it easier to get right.

Here is an approximate implementation (which I haven't tested):

```
int weightedSumAtAllLevels(BTNode node, int level) {
    if (node != null) {
        return level * node.getKey() +
               weightedSumAtAllLevels(node.getLeftChild(), level + 1) +
               weightedSumAtAllLevels(node.getRightChild(), level + 1);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I leave it as an exercise to figure out how this should be called for the root node.

Comment: call for root node with level=1 and as we move down step up level+1. your solution is succinct and elegant :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just start with the root and initialize level = 1.

```
sum = root.key()*level + weightedSum( root.left(), level + 1 ) + weightedSum( root.right(), level + 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

For hint.. Do a DFS traversal over the tree. Then for each depth sum the value of nodes and multiply with depth+1.